# Import Outlook Calendar Appointment from One account to another in Python/VBA

Tags: python, vba, outlook, calendar, pywin32

Actually I am trying to Export the calendar appointment from one outlook account to another outlook account but I have trayed so many time and end-up with just extracted appointment in an excel sheet and importing the same into another account. I don't have to much knowledge of VBA but I have used via internet and got this -

```html
Private Sub Outlook_Vba_Get_Calendar_Item_Appoinments()
    Dim oWorkbook As Workbook, Calendar_To_Excel_File As String
    Dim oOutlook_Calendar As Outlook.Folder, oCalendar_Items As Outlook.Items
    Dim oCalendarAppointment As Outlook.AppointmentItem
    Dim iRow As Double

    iRow = 1

    'Change path of the Target File name if required
    Calendar_To_Excel_File = "D:\Sample23434.xlsx"
    'Check if Output File already exists
    If VBA.Dir(Calendar_To_Excel_File) = "" Then
        'To Create New Workbook
        Set oWorkbook = Workbooks.Add
        oWorkbook.SaveAs Calendar_To_Excel_File
    Else
        'To Refer Already Created Workbook
        Set oWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(Calendar_To_Excel_File)
    End If
    
    'Get object reference for Outlook Calendar folder
    Set oOutlook_Calendar = Outlook.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
    Set oCalendar_Items = oOutlook_Calendar.Items
    
    'Loop Thru Each Items in Outlook Calendar
    For Each oCalendarAppointment In oCalendar_Items
        oWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(iRow, 1) = oOutlook_Calendar.FolderPath
        oWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(iRow, 2) = oCalendarAppointment.Start
        oWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(iRow, 3) = oCalendarAppointment.End
        oWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(iRow, 4) = oCalendarAppointment.Subject
        oWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(iRow, 5) = oCalendarAppointment.Location
        oWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(iRow, 6) = oCalendarAppointment.Duration
        oWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(iRow, 7) = oCalendarAppointment.Size
        'oWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(irow, 8) = oCalendarAppointment.Body
        iRow = iRow + 1
    Next

    'Save Excel Workbook With Calendar Appointments
    oWorkbook.Save
    oWorkbook.Close False  'Close Workbook without any Warning
    MsgBox "Outlook Calendar Appointments Downloaded To:" & Calendar_To_Excel_File

End Sub
```

If any one know how can I do this without using Excel please let me know with either Python or VBA

Comment: What do you mean by "export"? Just copy an appointment to another calendar folder? You can use `ApppointmentItem.Copy` / `ApppointmentItem.Move` for that.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko Actually I want to Copy an appointment from one outlook account and past the same appoint to a different Outlook account **(Not in different folder )** and thanks for your comment

Comment: It doesn't matter - `ApppointmentItem.Move` works across folders in different mailbox stores as long both the source and the target mailboxes are opened in Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

If you have got another account shared by a user (or just a calendar with required permissions to modify it) you could add a shared calendar to the Outlook profile and copy/move the required appointments directly without involving Excel workbooks for that.

The [NameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getshareddefaultfolder) method returns a `Folder` object that represents the specified default folder for the specified user. This method is used in a delegation scenario, where one user has delegated access to another user for one or more of their default folders (for example, their shared Calendar folder). For example, here is how you could use it to get the shared calendar folder in Outlook:

```
Sub ResolveName() 
 Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace 
 Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient 
 Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder 
 Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
 Set myRecipient = myNamespace.CreateRecipient("Eugene Astafiev")
 myRecipient.Resolve 
 If myRecipient.Resolved Then 
   Call ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient) 
 End If 
End Sub 
 
Sub ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient) 
 Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder 
 Set CalendarFolder = myNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(myRecipient, olFolderCalendar) 
 CalendarFolder.Display 
End Sub
```

After retrieving the target folder instance you can use the [AppointmentItem.Move](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.appointmentitem.move) or [AppointmentItem.CopyTo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.appointmentitem.copyto) methods.